# How to pass js Object and functions to a web component

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, web-component, custom-element

Hi All I am a beginner in javaScript and currently exploring JS Web-component and I got stuck due to some use cases

1 ) I want to pass a JS Object into my component like

```
<my-component data=obj ></my-component>
```

And require to use inside my component code Like

```
connectedCallback () {
    console.log(this.data) // it should print {"name":"xyz" , "role" : "dev"}
}
```

2 )  I also need to pass some functions or maybe call back functions like.

```
function myFunction(e){
   console.log(e)
}

<my-component click=myFunction ></my-component>
```

please try to add code snippet also in ans that will help me to learn more JS.
Thanks

Answer (score 18):

You should pass large object by Javascript.

Via a custom element method:

```
let comp = document.querySelector( 'my-component' )
comp.myMethod( obj )
```

Or setting a property:

```
comp.data = obj
```

Comment: For function, it will be the same. If you use LitHTML there is a special syntax to pass objects through attributes `<my-comp .things=${myObj}>...` but using the JavaScript way is the way to go

Answer (score 13):

It is best to pass in complex data using a property and not an attribute.

```js
myEl.data = {a:1,b:'two'};
```

The standard `on` events work fine on a custom element:

```js
function myFunction(e){
  alert(JSON.stringify(e.target.data));
  e.target.data = {a:1,b:"two"};
}

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._data = 0;
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML="Click Me";
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {

    }
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }
  set data(newVal) {
    this._data = newVal;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

```html
<my-component onclick="myFunction(event)"></my-component>
```

If your component dispatches a custom event then it is best to access it through code:

```
function specialEventHandler(evt) {
  // do something
}

myEl.addEventListener('special-event;', specialEventHandler);
```

Comment: What is the specific reasoning that this is "better" than passing through attributes. It seems equally complex to me.

Comment: passing through a property is simple JS: `el.property = {complex value} Passing through an attribute requires parsing logic.

Answer (score 7):

I did a Udemy course with Andreas Galster and the tutor passed in a JSON object via attribute.

As you can see it needs encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent as well to

```
attributeChangedCallback (name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (newValue && name === 'profile-data') {
            this.profileData = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(newValue));
            this.removeAttribute('profile-data');
        }
    
        this.render();
    }
```

Pass in:

```
<profile-card profile-data=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(profile))}>

</profile-card>
```

The code worked fine for me.

Comment: This only works if you're using the component in javascript space. How would I do it if the component is used in html doc?

Comment: @chovy you could add a script tag to the html file or just include a separate JS file

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1) You need to use `JSON.stringify(obj)`
Ad 2) As far as I know All attributes need to be defined as strings. You can pass the function that is global and inside component try to `eval(fn)`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your ans 

1) JSON.stringify(obj) i have tried but it is not giving me full data there may be some limit on attribute length

2) eval(fun) is also not working as the component is getting rendered in shadow dom not in actual dom so the scope issues